# Uploading files to media folder in Magento backend

Tags: magento, file-upload, module, backend

I've been trying to find the best way to upload simple text files in a subfolder of Magento's `media` folder by using an upload form. The idea is to add my own menu item to the Magento backend that shows a simple upload form when clicked by a backend user. This form should allow the user to select a text file from their computer and to then upload it into the `media` folder.

I did a lot of research and have found [this promising tutorial](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/admin/how_to_create_pdf_upload_in_backend_for_own_module). I am currently not experienced in Magento development, but I trust I can implement my ideas by tweaking this code here and there. However, I have run into several problems when trying to figure out how it works.

First off, the writer mentions: "First lets suppose you created a custom module with the module creator." I assumed he is referring to [this one](http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/). So, I created a module with this, only with "Need Backend Page" set to "Yes". In the next steps of the tutorial, I should edit `/app/code/local/Company/ModName/Block/Adminhtml/ModName/Edit/Form.php`, but that file is not present in any directory of the auto-created custom module. The only files/folders present, are:

```
- Company_ModName
    - app
        - code
        |   -local
        |       - Company
        |            - ModName
        |               - Block
        |               |   - Adminhtml
        |               |       - ModNamebackend.php
        |               - controllers
        |               |   - Adminhtml
        |               |       - ModnamebackendController.php
        |               - etc
        |               |   - config.xml
        |               - Helper
        |                   - Data.php
        - design
        |   - adminhtml
        |       - default
        |           - default
        |               - layout
        |               |   - modname.xml
        |               - template
        |                   - modname
        |                       - modnamebackend.phtml
        - etc
            - modules
                - Company_ModName.xml
```

And then, in the next step of the tutorial, in `/app/code/local/Company/ModName/controllers/Adminhtml/ModuleNameController.php` of which I assume is **not** the same file as `/app/code/local/Company/ModName/controllers/Adminhtml/ModnamebackendController.php`, which is present above, I should add some code after `if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {` in `saveAction()`. I cannot find this `if` statement anywhere.

How is this possible? What am I doing wrong, what can I do to fix it? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you still want to know "the best way to upload simple text files to media folder" from magento admin, this is what I would do:

- Create a module, made it depends on Mage_Cms
- Add your module's config.xml (or adminhtml.xml) as below:

```html
<config>
     <adminhtml>                
        <cms>
            <browser>               
                <extensions>
                    <allowed>
                        <txt>1</txt>                        
                    </allowed>                    
                </extensions>                
            </browser>
        </cms>
    </adminhtml>       
</config>
```

Then you can use the standard magento upload.